# Creating class object

Tags: perl

I am getting:

```
Can't call method "test" without a package or object reference at 4.pl line 6.
```

And i don't know why, any ideas?

Users.pm

```
package Users; 
sub new{
    print "Created\n"; 
}
sub test{
    print "a";
}
1;
```

Test.pl

```
BEGIN {
  push @INC,"/home/baddc0re/Desktop/perl_test/";
}
use Users;
$user = new Users();
$user->test();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to you use syntax `$users = Users->new()` instead of `new Users`. You forgot to [bless](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/bless.html) values inside `new` method. Please read [`perlootut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlootut.html) under perldoc.

**Users.pm**

```
package Users;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;

    my $self = {};
    bless $self, $class;
    return $self;
}

sub test {
    print "a";
}

1;
```

**MAIN**

```
use strict;
use Users;

my $users = Users->new();
print $users->test();
```

Answer (score 3):

Object construction in Perl doesn't work that way.  The constructor has to explicitly return a reference that has been made into an object with [the `bless` function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/bless.html); in fact, in Perl, this is what defines a constructor, as "`new`" is just another name for a subroutine and, unlike in C++, invoking a function named `new` does not force Perl to create an object.  In this specific example, `new` is just returning the return value of `print`, which is presumably just some true value, and trying to invoke the `test` method on this value fails because it hasn't been blessed into any class.